# Kentico 12: System Wide Macro Failures

Tags: kentico

Quick qualification: I have been developing on the Kentico platform since V7, spanning more than a decade. I have used every license from EMS to Free Edition, and consider myself a Kentico expert. I regularly build custom Web Parts, Form Controls, Modules, Scheduled Tasks, Integrations and more with a great deal of success.

About a week ago, I started encountering catastrophic macro failures on one of my sites, and as I go on to explain in more detail, keep in mind that I have already ***Resigned*** the Macros many times in an effort to resolve this issue. My Event log is FULL of macro errors:

[image: Event Log] [image: RESOLVEDATAMACRO Error] [image: Unigrid Error]

When this first occurred over a week ago, I tried all of the obvious things (resigning macros, restarting application pools etc.). After many hours of failed attempts, I eventually created a whole new site from a fresh deployment, created a new database and rebuilt the site from scratch, and everything seemed to be working fine. For a day or two. Then again, the same problem occurred. This time I created a fresh deployment from scratch and connected it to the second database (the first one I recreated), and it worked again. For a while. Until it didn't. Now I'm here again, facing the same issues, and I don't understand what keeps causing the issue.

There simply must be something about my code base or my environment that is causing this issue, but I don't know enough about the Kentico code under the hood to pinpoint where to look. Anyone with a similar experience, or a Kentico expert who could offer some assistance would be appreciated beyond belief.

NOTE: I do not extend or customize any code in the `CMSApp` project. The only changes I make inside that folder is `web.config` app settings, connection strings etc. My project is branched from a fresh install of K12, and all of my custom code and components goes into separate projects.

EDIT: This problem occurs while debugging from Visual Studio (2019 Enterprise on Windows 10 Pro) as well as when deployed on the production server (Windows Server 2016 on Azure VM).

Comment: Have you recently upgraded the site from an older version or is this a new install?  Has the user who originally signed those macros been deleted?

Comment: @BrendenKehren - Thanks for the response. The site was not upgraded. K12 straight from the installer, not even any hotfixes.The only user is default GlobalAdministrator.

Comment: Try applying the lastest hotfix, resign macros and see if this clears things up.  Never stay on the vanilla XX.0 version of any Kentico release.

Comment: What is the hash salt string set? Are you doing any export/import, staging or code deployment? If yes, make sure the hash salt is the same on all environments. What other changes were made before the errors started? Something must have been changed if it was working fine for months before.

Comment: @BrendenKehren - After Hotfix 12.0.91 I am unable to log out. NRE in Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException. Installed a fresh 12.0.29, executed hotfix, error is replicated.

Comment: @jurajo - Just regular development. Did not change CMSHashStringSalt until AFTER the issue, trying to resolve it. Have since reverted it. Unrelated.

Comment: What else has been changed about a week ago? There must have been some change. Do you have e.g. some older backups? I would try restoring them to see if you replicate the issue. If not, then compare with the current project. What are the VS settings? URL, build/debug settings?

Comment: @jurajo - Nothing has changed. That's what I'm trying to tell you. If you want to help, please help my understand how to FIX it, I don't care what caused it anymore. My project has stopped completely for over a week, I'm now officially losing money every day. Is it a data issue? IIS issue? Code issue? Browser? Point me in some meaningful direction, please.

Comment: Also note the Unigrid error prevents design tabs from loading throughout the application, preventing me from editing any page templates, completely stalling the development effort.

Comment: I am sorry but without knowing what was changed it is impossible to tell. I am not a magician and in some cases you need to find the root cause to remove all its symptoms. If it was working before, something must have been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was a glitch in a `Custom Macro Namespace` that I was registering from my `Custom Module`. Apparently something in that registration process brought down the entire `Macro Engine`. I don't actually know specifically what the glitch is, as for the sake of expedience I've scrapped the custom macros entirely. I may reintroduce them later with caution, now that I know the impact that they can have on the Kentico application as a whole, but for now I need to get this project launched.

I can't be certain why it started acting up after all these months, as the macros within the namespace were not in use anywhere, but at least I (we) have the answer. I'm surprised that there was no log entry to indicate the issue was related to a custom macro registration, and the lack thereof certainly cost me many hours of diagnostics, but I'm thankful to share that the issue is indeed behind me, at long last.

Answer (score 0):

Try using beyond compare to file compare the website with issues to a same version same hotfix one. See if there are any obvious differences to the file system. Missing xml for the views etc. Is the global administrator deleted or set to not allowed? Can you make a new god level user, set macros to that user?